# Google drive api v3 c# Uploadprogress trigger during file Upload

Tags: c#, api, google-drive-api

I am using Drive api to upload files.
Uploading is working properly also progress is firing.But it is  firing after upload has finished.I want progress trigger simultaneously while uploading and response on the web page.
Tried this code.

```
        protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await RunDownloadAsync();
        }

        private async Task RunDownloadAsync()
        {
            Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File asd = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
            asd = await Task.Run(() => upload(path, filename));    
        }

        public async Task<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> upload(string _fileloc, string filename)
        {
           request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, GetMimeType(_fileloc));
                //   request = service.Files.Create();

                request.Fields = "*";
                request.ChunkSize = 262144;
               request.ProgressChanged += (IUploadProgress)=> Request_ProgressChanged1(IUploadProgress);


                await Task.Run(()=> request.UploadAsync());
            }
            //  return request.ResponseBody;
            // var aaaa = request.ResponseBody;


            return request.ResponseBody;
        }


        private  void Request_ProgressChanged1(IUploadProgress obj)
        {
            double pc = (obj.BytesSent * 100) / FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            File.AppendAllText(@"d:\date.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + obj.Status.ToString() + " - " + obj.BytesSent + "____" + pc.ToString("0.00") + Environment.NewLine);
             Label2.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + obj.Status.ToString() + " - " + obj.BytesSent + "____" + pc + "<br>";
            Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + obj.Status.ToString() + " - " + obj.BytesSent + "____" + pc + "<br>");
            // close the stream

            //  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format(obj.Status + " " + obj.BytesSent));
            //   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(obj.BytesSent.ToString());

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Is the transfer using HTTP 1.0 (stream mode) or HTPP 1.0 (chunk mode)?

Comment: sorry ddnt understand your question..it is asp.net c# web application running on localhost..

Comment: There are two HTP modes.  If you are using 1.0 the response is a single stream and is not chunked.  So if you are using 1.0 you will only get event at the end.

Comment: how to set chunk or stream mode!!!

Comment: First check what is being used with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  The server may only support one mode (or both).  Check what the default mode is being used with sniffer.  Then if wrong mode try overriding.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to server not supporting chunked upload.

In my case, it was due to `request.ChunkSize` not specified. Google Drive API v3 uploads files in chunks. The default chunk size is 10485760 bytes (as defined in `ResumableUpload.DefaultChunkSize`). Hence that is equal to around 10 MB.

When you don't specify ChunkSize, it uploads file in 10 MB  chunks. If your file is smaller than 10 MB, it will upload the entire file in one chunk and `request.ProgressChanged` will only be fired once ie. after the chunk upload finishes. Hence, specify `ChunkSize` equal to something that is multiple of 262144 (bytes) as mentioned in ChunkSize summary (Chunk size must be a multiple of ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize to be compatible with Google upload servers).

**Hence setting this worked:**

```cs
request.ChunkSize = 262144; // or anything multiple of MinimumChunkSize
```